# Width of Datagrid columns WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem with setting a width on my WPF datagrid, I have 2 columns, one for Name and one for Email, I like both to be atleast 100, but if Name is longer, I like it to take as much space as needed. Right now both just end up 100 width no mater how wide the datagrid itself gets. This is how I tried it:

**Edited code:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="MemberDataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="30" Width="Auto" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="30" Width="*" Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="SelectMemeberButton" Click="SelectMemeberButton_Clicked" Margin="10,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Add member"></Button>
        <Button Name="RemoveMemeberButton" Margin="0,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Remove member" Click="RemoveMemeberButton_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you post your window xaml? Which is the type of the control that contains your DataGrid?

Comment: The grid is in a StackPanel, I edited the code

Comment: Indeed i tried your code (I used a StackPanel too), but the Name column seems to work in the way that you wish... If you need I can post my code.

Comment: Yeah the name one is fine, the problem is that the Email one is not filling out the rest of the space, it just sits at 30 until you manually change the size... If you code fixes that I would love to see it! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's something I'm missing in your problem and I can't see the point. If I look at your window, I have the impression that everything works as it should.

This is the code I used:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new Person[] {
            new Person() { Name = "Paul Leary", Email="paul@contoso.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Andy Dale", Email="andy@contoso.com" },
            new Person() { Name = "Mike 'The Firestarter' Douglas", Email = "an_incredibly_long_email_address@contoso.com" }
        };

    }
}
```

And this is the window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="600">

    <StackPanel Margin="4">
        <DataGrid Name="MemberDataGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col1" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Col2" MinWidth="100" Width="*" Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Path=Email}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Col2, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If you run this code you can see that first column is about 164 width. At the same time the second column fits all the remaining space (about 384). So, does this code work in the way that you need?